# PHP doing multiple sorts with same $result resource

Tags: php, mysql

I am not sure how this would work, but I have 6000 student marks that belong to approximately 900 students. I can do several select functions on this data to get a reasonable answer but I have to put that information into a spreadsheet to delete the students who have not met the criteria. Is there a better way?

If I do my first select to get each unique student name, then can I then sort through the results for averages over 80. This is not an issue, but I would like to drop those that did not meet this criteria and then do another select for those students that have less than 8 courses, and drop those. Then go though the final list and drop any student who does not have a 80 in English.

I can do each as an individual select statement, but I want to store each result and use that in the next step. In the end I would like to end up with a list of students who have 80 average, 8 courses, min 80 in English ...

I know this is possible (if not it would be crazy) but what would be the best and most efficient method of doing this, June marks would be 24000 marks so I am guessing using 6 select queries is not the best method? I am using PHP and MYSQL for this.

I hope that this is enough information and I really appreciate any insight into this.

Thanks

PS here is the table structure:

```
table: students_marks
id  stud_id gr  student_#   year   course  term  mark per

415 31703   9   3100992316  2500    PHYE9   F1  78  78
416 31703   9   3100992316  2500    FR9     F1  50  50
417 31703   9   3100992316  2500    ENG9    F1  55  55 

student_unique
id   student_#   First   Last   gr 
50  3100992316  Amanda  B       9
```

I seperated it into two tables just to keep the first sort for unique students easier but after reading the answer below I see it probably would have been better to put all the data into one table. Oh and if you are wondering why mark and percent, IB has marks out of 7 so they have to be converted to something normal when doing calculations.

Comment: Sounds like this can be done in a single query. Can you please provide your table(s) structure(s) so we have something to work with?

Answer (score 0):

If all your data is in the same table you could do all those filters in the same Select statement. Something like

```
SELECT AVG(Grades) As Average, StudentID,StudentName, Count(StudentCourses) As "Courses" FROM Students Where Average >= 80 AND Courses >= 8;
```

Otherwise you will need to do a join or two. I would have to see your table to give a better answer.

Comment: The data is in two tables but I can do a join on them quite easy. Didn't realize that you could do a AVG(grades) and a count(studentcourses) in the same select statement, that will probably get what I need. Thanks for the help, that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'd get into [Doctrine's ArrayCollection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html) to perform that kind of task. But you can do it with good old array_filter as well.

Let's say you store the unfiltered result in an array `$all_students`

```
$all_students = $connection
                    ->query("select * from students")
                    ->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**Using array_filter**

```
$over_80_avg = array_filter($all_students, function($student, $index) {
    return $student['avg'] >= 80;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH));

$less_8_courses = array_filter($over_80_avg, function($student, $index) {
    return $student['courses_count'] <= 8;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH));
```

**With Doctrine ArrayCollection**

It might be overkill to get into doctrine (which probably means getting into composer if you haven't) just to perform this, but it will pay for itself eventually.

Instance an ArrayCollection from the original array:

```
$all_students_collection= new Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection($all_students);
```

(please note I'm using the fully qualified namespace as I don't know anything else about your code)

ArrayCollections allow you to perform filters like so:

```
$over_80_avg_collection = $all_students_collection->filter(function($student) {
    return $student->avg >= 80;
});
```

Then every new variable you declare can be a subfilter of the former or from the main one:

```
$less_8_courses_collection = $over_80_avg_collection->filter(function($student) {
    return $student->courses_count <= 8;
});
```

Finally, you'd need to cast these collections back to arrays to meet your original intention:

```
$over_80_avg = $over_80_avg_collection->toArray();
$less_8_courses = $less_8_courses_collection->toArray();
```

**Another way** would be to go straight into a library that's just meant to add sugar syntax to arrays, like [Underscore.php](http://anahkiasen.github.io/underscore-php/).

Either way, you need to treat your original array as an inmutable, so by any means avoid any method that passes the array as a reference, for it will drop rows from the original array as well.